# How can I insert a tracking image in my blog under wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress, images, tracking

I have a blog under wordpress.com and I inserted a fake image tag for analyzing visitors in widget like this:

```
<img src="http://www.my-cgi.com/cgi-bin/acclog.cgi?url=http://myblog.wordpress.com/">
```

But from June, 2016, seems like wordpress.com uses some cache and they convert the tag to like this:

```
<img src="https://i1.wp.com/www.my-cgi.com/cgi-bin/acclog.cgi">
```

Now I can't get the actual log of the visitors. Is there any way to insert image tag in my blog under wordpress.com without hitting cache?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that wordpress.com doesn't allow HTTP link. That's why it convert it to the cached contents with HTTPS. 
I moved my CGI to HTTPS enabled host and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/image/location.png">
```

from a security perspective what your attempting to do by manipulating the URL parameter to get an external sites resource is not safe.

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried your tag but actually it has been escaped: 
    &lt;img src=&quot;"&gt;